# dll dependency problem - 3rd party package(Nuget) overrides the other in the output folder System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget-package, dll-dependency

**Goal**: control the output dll without saving or adding the artifact to the repository.

The main issue is that I have two **3rd party packages in my solution** (.net framwork 4.6.1):
rabbitMQClient V6.0.0 that use - system.memory (>= 4.5.4) -> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (>= 4.5.3)

MongoBson v2.12.1 that use System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe (>= 5.0.0) (for example)

every package provide the following System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll with different version and since they are different project every one of them overrides the other in the output directory.

what I tried:
If I try to **downgrade** the "CompilerServices.Unsafe" the mongoDb connection failed due to exception - The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper..."

if I **upgrade** then the rabbit won't connect  - inner exception: Could not load file or assembly.

I tried to use redirect but it seems that its not working (rabbitMq exception if its the new version of the dll)

The only possibility for the solution to **work** is if I set the copy local to false at all the projects except the project that uses the old version **but** since at NuGet update it will set to true I need more stable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade is not a viable option; upgrade should usually work *but you'll need to fix the assembly bindings*; `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe` is well-known as one of those that is a major pain here, complicated by the fact that the auto-binding generation code *just doesn't work right for it*; Nick has good guidance on how to do this [here](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2020/02/11/binding-redirects/) - and the main config examples happen to use `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe`, so it should just be a case of adding the current version numbers.

This is one of many many things that just gets a lot easier in .NET Core / .NET 5 onwards.